# When is $a=\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{2}v^2)$ used instead of $a=\frac{dv}{dx}v$?

Tags: integration

In the context of getting an equation with the acceleration ($a$) being expressed in terms of either velocity ($v$) or displacement ($x$), I would like to know how the first equation can be used.
The latter equation is useful because it has the terms $dv$ and $dx$ allowing for separation of variables. If $a$ is given in terms of either $v$ or $x$, you can integrate.

However, I can't see in what situations the first equation would be used. I thought it could be when everything is in terms of x but even if $a$ is in terms of $x$, $v$ is unknown.

Comment: For $\frac{d}{dx}(\frac12v^2)$ to make sense, you need $v$ to be a function of $x$. If you know $v$ explicitly in terms of $x$, you can either first write $\frac12v^2$ and then differentiate (with respect to $x$) or you can compute $\frac{dv}{dx}$ and then multiply $\frac{dv}{dx}v$. I guess if you know $\frac{dv}{dx}$ but not $v$, then it might still be useful to write down $a=\frac{dv}{dx}v$.

Comment: Thanks, I understand how you can differentiate to go from $v$ to $a$ now. Do you know any cases where you could use the first equation for integration from $a$ to $v$?